# Which episode to start watching One Piece from to see Ace and WhiteBeard getting involved?

Tags: one-piece

I want to start watching One Piece again but don't want to start from the beginning. I know most of the beginning where they assemble a crew and fight Arlong, Buggy, Crocodile.

I want to start at a point where all the big badass characters like Ace and WhiteBeard are involved while still knowing what's going on.  Which is the best episode to start from?

Comment: I suggest you to see it from beginning for better understanding but if you insist to see Ace and Whitebeard in action, probably from [Sabaody Archipelago Arc](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Sabaody_Archipelago_Arc) starting from episode 385

Comment: I've seen most of the begging a couple times lol. Wheres a good place to start to not miss anything big but not in the begging like when they're still getting together.

Comment: @Sealkyuubinaruto That would probably be Sabaody Archipelago or Marineford Arc.

Answer (score 7):

It's difficult to give an objective answer, so I'll summarize the arcs to give you an understanding where you should start watching without giving too much spoiler. I'll stick to recurring characters and exclude filler arcs, as I haven't watched those. For the exact episode numbers refer to [this page](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Story_Arcs).

If you want to skip to where *all the big badass characters like Ace and WhiteBeard are involved* you should **skip to the Marineford Arc**. In that arc you will see an all-out war going down between Whitebeard and the Marines to save Ace. I would recommend you to **start at the Sabaody Archipelago Arc** though, where a lot of new characters were introduced that will recur in the story. You could skip inbetween arcs if you want. If you would do so, you'd only have missed the introduction of Franky and Brook and the backstory on Robin.

## East Blue

> First half of the Straw Hat pirates are introduced.

- *Romance Dawn Arc*:

  - Introduction of Luffy, Zoro, Coby, Red Hair pirates, (Alvida and Helmeppo).
  - Luffy rescues Coby and Zoro from the marines.
- *Orange Town Arc*:

  - Introduction of Nami, Buggy (and his pirates).
  - Strawhat pirates vs Buggy pirates.
- *Syrup Village Arc*:

  - Introduction of Usopp, Going Merry, (and Jango).
  - Strawhat pirates vs Black Cat pirates.
- *Baratie Arc*:

  - Introduction of Sanji, Mihawk, (Fullbody, Johnny and Yosaku).
  - Strawhat pirates vs Krieg Pirates.
- *Arlong Park Arc*:

  - Introduction of Arlong, Hachi, (and Mohmoo).
  - Backstory on Nami and Strawhat pirates vs Arlong pirates.
- *Loguetown Arc*:

  - Introduction of Smoker, Tashigi and Dragon.
  - Luffy will be Pirate King.

## Alabasta

> Robin and Chopper join the crew.

- *Reverse Mountain Arc*:

  - Introduction of Laboon, Crocus and the Rumbar pirates.
  - Strawhat pirates enter the grand line.
- *Whiskey Peak Arc*:

  - Introduction of Baroque Works and Vivi.
  - Zoro vs Baroque Works.
- *Little Garden Arc*:

  - Introduction of Mr 3 and two giants of Elbaf, Dorry and Brogy.
  - Strawhat pirates vs Baroque Works.
- *Drum Island Arc*:

  - Introduction of Chopper.
  - Strawhat pirates vs king Wapol.
- *Alabasta Arc*:

  - Introduction of Robin, Mr 2, Mr 1, Crocodile, Ace.
  - Strawhat pirates vs Baroque Works.

## Sky Island

> Introduction of some of those bad-ass characters.

- *Jaya Arc*:

  - Introduction of Sengoku, Tsuru, Kuma, Doflamingo, Gorosei, Whitebeard pirates, Blackbeard pirates and Noland.
  - Getting ready to go to Skypiea.
- *Skypiea Arc*:

  - Introduction of sky islands.
  - Strawhat pirates vs god Enel and his priests.

## Water 7

> Franky joins the crew.

- *Long Ring Long Land Arc*:

  - Introduction of Aokiji.
  - Strawhat pirates vs Foxy pirates.
- *Water 7 Arc*:

  - Introduction of Franky, Sogeking, Thousand Sunny, (Spandam and CP9).
  - Strawhat pirates vs Franky Family
  - Luffy vs Usopp
  - Sanji, Sogeking and Franky vs CP9.
- *Enies Lobby Arc*:

  - Backstory on Robin and Strawhats learn new battle techniques.
  - Strawhat pirates vs CP9.
- *Post-Enies Lobby Arc*:

  - Introduction of Garp and Dadan.
  - Ace vs Blackbeard.

## Thriller Bark

> Brook joins the crew.

- *Thriller Bark Arc*:

  - Introduction of Brook, Moriah, (Perona, and Lola).
  - Strawhat pirates vs warlord Moriah
  - Strawhat pirates vs Kuma.

## Summit War

> Shit goes down.

- *Sabaody Archipelago Arc*:

  - Introduction of Duval, Kizaru, Rayleigh, the Eleven Supernovas, World Nobels, (Fisher Tiger and his Sun pirates).
  - Strawhat pirates vs Rosy Life Riders.
  - Eleven Supernovas vs admiral Kizaru and Pacifista.
  - Strawhat pirates vs admiral Kizaru.
- *Amazon Lily Arc*:

  - Introduction of Boa Hancock.
  - Luffy finds out Ace has been imprisoned by the Marines.
- *Impel Down Arc*:

  - Introduction of Jinbe, Ivankov and Magellan.
  - Luffy brings chaos to Impel Down prison.
- *Marineford Arc*:

  - Introduction of Akainu, Blackeard's new crewmembers.
  - All-out-war of Whitebeard pirates and their allies vs the marines and the shichibukai in order to save Ace from execution.
- *Post-War Arc*:

  - Introduction of Sabo and Haki.
  - Backstory on Luffy, Ace and Sabo.
  - Three year training-timeskip of the Strawhat pirates.

## Fishman Island

> A glimps of the new techniques the Strawhats learned during the timeskip.

- *Return to Sabaody Arc*:

  - Strawhat pirates regroup after their training.
- *Fishman Island Arc*:

  - Introduction of Shirahoshi, Big Mom and Koala.
  - Strawhat pirates vs New Fishman Pirates.
  - Backstory on the Sun pirates.

## Pirate Alliance

> Doflamingo doing a lot of sick shit.

- *Punk Hazard Arc*:

  - Introduction of Dr. Vegapunk, Caesar Clown, Kaido, Kin'emon and Momonosuke.
  - Strawhat pirates and Heart pirates form an alliance.
  - Strawhat pirates and Law vs Caesar and the Donquixote pirates.
- *Dressrosa Arc (ongoing)*:

  - Introduction of Tontatta, CP0, Fujitora, Bartolomeo, and A LOT of other characters that might make a recurrence in future arcs.
  - Strawhat pirates vs Donquixote pirates.

Comment: FYI, the main suggestion as to where to start is the same as my answer (unless you specifically don't think he should watch Strong World).  The Sabaody Archipelago Arc starts on episode 382.

Comment: @kaine 385 actually. 382~384 is filler. Aside from that I agree and upvoted cos I agree. I posted more details on other arcs for others that might not be as interested in badass fights as much as OP also cos boredom.

Comment: This is a nice summary, I love it. Please update this till the current arc. thank you. :)

Answer (score 6):

You can find *One Piece* episodes to watch on [Hulu](http://www.hulu.com/one-piece).

Crocodile is at the end of season 2, so you will want to start from season 3. Ace also shows up in season 3 from the thumbnails on Hulu.

Most of the episodes are [subbed](http://www.hulu.com/grid/one-piece?categories=subtitled), but season 3 and 5 are [dubbed](http://www.hulu.com/grid/one-piece?categories=dubbed) (season 4 is not available dubbed for whatever reason).

Another popular site to watch is CrunchyRoll, you can watch [Season 3](http://www.crunchyroll.com/one-piece/episode-136-zenny-of-the-island-of-goats-and-the-pirate-ship-in-the-mountains-651953) there, too. However, all the episodes are subbed.

Comment: Just saying, but Hulu is only accessible from within the States.

Answer (score 2):

I am biased and would prefer to watch it from the beginning... largely because I love the show and want to do that myself if I had the time.  Nevertheless, you don't need to watch everything in order to know what is going on now. The start of each arc is an acceptable place to try and pick up the show (though you will miss things obviously).

**I would recommend that you start from episode 382**, you will get to know the whole crew a just after they are finally assembled. Before this point there are several entertaining arcs in which the crew progresses through the East Blue and then Grand Line fighting Big Bads and gathers new members.  The current crew becomes whole in episode 381.  You get to see them in one arc together (which provides very important information) and then BIG things happen.  You will meet the characters who are the big players in the world as Luffy does and will get quick overviews of the now underpowered big bads from he previous arcs. This is a major turning point for the show and I don't think there is another good place to pick it up again until episode 517.  If you start there you will have missed the exact badasses you want to see.

Additionally, I would recommend you watch Strong World.  It is a canon movie between (i think) episodes 381 and 382.

Do not think, however, that I am saying that the first 381 episodes are not worth watching.  They are amazing and provide important backstory to every character.

I prefer subs and don't know where to find dubs anywhere but Hulu. Sorry for not being able to answer that part.